# structure of DTM

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

```
 > str(dtm)
List of 6
 $ i       : int [1:128403] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ j       : int [1:128403] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ v       : num [1:128403] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ nrow    : int 500
 $ ncol    : int 8330
```

Could anyone please tell me what "i","j","v" here represent? Thanks!

Comment: if I use dtm$v, I will get a sequence of number. Could you please tell me what does these numbers represent? Cuz nrow denotes the number of rows, ncol denotes the number of columns, so I don't know what other number actually means. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A dtm is basically a simple triplet matrix.

If you read the help with simple triplet matrix (`?slam::simple_triplet_matrix`) you can read the following:

> i, j Integer vectors of row and column indices, respectively.
>
> v Vector of values.
>
> nrow, ncol     Integer values specifying the number of rows and columns,
>   respectively. Defaults are the maximum row and column indices,
>   respectively